# Sorting graph from higher to lower

Tags: vue.js, charts

Please advise any Vue component for graph that can be sorted from higher to lower. I have data:

```js
labels: [day1, day2, day3]
 datasets: [
   {label: 'Nike', data: [10, 30, 40]},
   {label: 'Adidas', data: [20, 15, 35]},
   {label: 'Puma', data: [5, 20, 15]}
]
```

[Graph vue-chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O03om.png)

I need to show data for every day sortingfrom higher to lower
Day1 - 20,10,5 (now i see 10,20,5)

Is it possible? Can anyone suggest a component for js?

Comment: I have extended my answer with an example component. Can you show/sketch what you want to reach? And please use the comments to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a computed property:

```js
const datasets: [
  { label: 'Nike', data: [10, 30, 40] },
  { label: 'Adidas', data: [20, 15, 35] },
  { label: 'Puma', data: [5, 20, 15] }
]
```

```js
computed: {
  sortedDays() {
    return datasets.map(dataset => {
      return dataset.data.map(day => day).sort((a, b) => b - a)
    })
  }
}
// sortedDays returns this array:
//  [ [ 40, 30, 10 ], [ 35, 20, 15 ], [ 20, 15, 5 ] ]
```

In the next step you have to use sortedDays with its index instead of dataset[idx].data.

This works with the index, because your dataset is an array, so simply access data via the index with the values of the computed property. Is it understandable so far?

### working component:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(label, idx) in labels">
      {{ idx }}: {{ label }}: data sorted {{ sortedDays[idx] }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      labels: ['day1', 'day2', 'day3'],
      datasets: [
        { label: 'Nike', data: [10, 30, 40] },
        { label: 'Adidas', data: [20, 15, 35] },
        { label: 'Puma', data: [5, 20, 15] }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedDays() {
      return this.datasets.map(dataset => {
        return dataset.data.map(day => day).sort((a, b) => b - a)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### output:

```
// { idx }}: {{ label }}: data sorted {{ sortedDays[idx] }}
0: day1: data sorted [ 40, 30, 10 ]
1: day2: data sorted [ 35, 20, 15 ]
2: day3: data sorted [ 20, 15, 5 ]
```